# Access React component from Socket IO listener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

When I listen for a `'new-message'` event I am trying to call my `Dashboard` component's `createMessage` function:

```
var socket = io.connect()

socket.on('new-message', (data) => {
    console.log("ALL CLIENTS SHOULD GET THIS MESSAGE")
    Dashboard.createMessage(data.id, data.body, data.context, data.urgent, data.customContext)
})

const Dashboard = React.createClass({

  createMessage: function(id, body, context, urgent, customContext) {

    this.setState({
      messages: [
        ...this.state.messages,
        {id: id, user_id: this.state.currentUser, body: body, context: context, urgent: urgent, customContext: customContext}
      ]
    })
   }
  })
```

However, I get an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Dashboard.createMessage is not a function`

Is there a way to access the `Dashboard` `createMessage` method from outside the component?

Alternatively is there a way to have the `Dashboard` `component` always listen for an event and I can do something like this:

```
var socket = io.connect()

const Dashboard = React.createClass({

  alwaysListenForEvent: function() {
      socket.on('new-message', (data) => {
          console.log("ALL CLIENTS SHOULD GET THIS MESSAGE")
          this.createMessage(data.id, data.body, data.context, data.urgent, data.customContext)
      })
  }

  createMessage: function(id, body, context, urgent, customContext) {

    this.setState({
      messages: [
        ...this.state.messages,
        {id: id, user_id: this.state.currentUser, body: body, context: context, urgent: urgent, customContext: customContext}
      ]
    })
   }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your Dashboard component with a Socket [HoC](https://medium.com/@franleplant/react-higher-order-components-in-depth-cf9032ee6c3e) or a [container component](https://medium.com/@learnreact/container-components-c0e67432e005).

Example code:

```
class SocketListener extends React.Component {
  state = {
    messages: []
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    socket.on('new-message', (data) => {
      this.setState({ messages: this.state.messages.concat(data) })
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Dashboard
        messages={this.state.messages}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

This way your Dashboard component does not need to know anything about the messages.